# How to alter a sql column consisting of binary flags?

Tags: sql, binary

I've got an Options column in an Attorney table that (unfortunately) consists of binary flags, like this:

```
0x0000000100010400010000000000000000000000
```

I need to do something along the lines of this (i.e. set all flags in the 4th and 6th positions to '0'):

```
update attorney
set substring(Options,4,1) = 0x00,
    substring(Options,6,1) = 0x00
where customercode in ('36526', '50015')
```

But that doesn't work.

Comment: When you use `set` you need to set the entire column value.  So, if you were to section out the specific substrings, replacing your value, and concatenate them together, it might work.

Comment: Thanks for the idea; I mentioned it to my supervisor and he helped spell it out for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As paqogomez suggested, I needed to set the entire column value. My supervisor agreed and helped me with the following query:

```
update attorney
set Options = substring(Options,1,3) + ‘0x00’ + substring(Options,5,1) + ‘0x00’ +      substring(Options,7,len(Options))
where customercode in ('36526', '50015')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is bad database design. It violates First Normal Form.  Instead of putting all these attributes in one column, each one should have its own row in a separate table.  So the "attorney" table would contain the column "customercode" and other non-repeating information for each attorney.  There would also be an "options" table which would look like this:

```
customercode optionsOn
36526        option1    
36526        option2    
50015        option3    
50015        option23
```

The "optionsOn" column contains the options that have a "1" value for the given customercode.

Comment: How is this an answer to OP's problem?!?  Yes, I agree that this would be a better solution, but it doesnt address the actual problem.  You have no idea if OP has control over their schema.

Comment: I was possibly wrong to assume that OP did have control over the schema.  I have mostly worked in very small companies where the programmer was always the admin

Comment: I was actually going to put a disclaimer in my question...but yes, I am painfully aware that this is horrible database design. : ) I'm just a junior developer though, and don't have any control over the schema.